# How to make a html table loaded in a <div> be a Datatable?

Tags: php, datatables, bootstrap-4

On my system, I have an HTML TABLE that is populated with DB data by XMLHttpRequest.

In the file search.php this is all the SQL queries and the AJAX function that does the queries in the DB and returns the data to be shown in the table. see below the return of the jaxax function.

```
var result = req.responseText;
document.getElementById ('resultado'). innerHTML = result;
```

Already in the list.php file is where we have the   that receives the data and displays the html table.

The question is how to make this table a DataTable and not a simple HTML table?
Because in the list.php page does not have the html table element, but rather a  and if I try to set the  element as Datatable does not work.

DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2

And if I replace the  element with  the table until it turns a datatable but no works.

Comment: What is exactly inside your `req.responseText`? Please provide some sample-output.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not know exactly what you asked for. what I can say is that data is returned from the database and presented in the table.
follows the link from a print of the system screen   https://ibb.co/ZmybmqJ